# Go import package: pkg found with go (-compiler gccgo), not found with gccgo

Tags: gcc, go, gccgo

Go/gccgo version: 6.3.0

I am building a program with `go build -compiler gccgo -x <args> <args> program.go`. Build process fails with

```
% /usr/bin/gccgo -c -g -fgo-pkgpath=<file_path>/common/flogging -fgo-relative-import-path=<file_path>/common/flogging -o <dest_path>/common/flogging/)obj/_go_.o ./logging.go (some program specific args omitted)
% <file_path>/common/flogging
common/flogging/logging.go:26:26: error: import file 'github.com/op/go-
logging' not found
  "github.com/op/go-logging"
                          ^
```

`logging.go` imports

```
import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "sync"

    "github.com/op/go-logging"
)
```

If I compile `logging.go` standalone with `go build`, it compiles fine:

```
[root@eef079aa0103 flogging]# go build logging.go 
[root@eef079aa0103 flogging]# go build -compiler gccgo logging.go
```

If I run the `/usr/bin/gccgo` command standalone, the error persists.

```
[root@eef079aa0103 flogging]# /usr/bin/gccgo <args> logging.go (args same with above) 
logging.go:26:26: error: import file 'github.com/op/go-logging' not found
  "github.com/op/go-logging"  
                          ^
```

I used `strace` to track

`% strace -f -o aa /usr/bin/gccgo <args> logging.go (args same with above)`

and found out that

`open("/opt/gopath/src/github.com/op/go-logging", O_RDONLY) = 10
open("/opt/gopath/src/github.com/op/go-logging.gox", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/gopath/src/github.com/op/libgo-logging.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/gopath/src/github.com/op/libgo-logging.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/gopath/src/github.com/op/go-logging.o", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

the compiler is able to find `go-logging` package in my $GOPATH, but it fails for not seeing anything with `.gox` `.so` `.a` or `.o` file.

Which agrees with whats on the Go website:

```
When you import the package FILE with gccgo, it will look for the import data in the following files, and use the first one that it finds.

FILE.gox FILE.o libFILE.so libFILE.a

The gccgo compiler will look in the current directory for import files
```

Any idea how could I resolve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: `go env` and tells us what your setup is.  Also may want to run `which go` and `which gccgo`

Comment: `gccgo` is just the compiler, it's not a replacement for the `go` tool. If you want to see how the compiler is invoked, use the `-x` flag: `go build -x -compiler gccgo logging.go`

Comment: @JimB You are right. My original attempt was to build a program, to which a Makefile (and inside, a 'go build' command) was already given. The build fails and I used the '-x' flag to narrow down to a 'gccgo' command where it could not import. The example above was just manually running that command standalone.

Comment: Updated the question with some clarifications and recent development.